# Раздела диска в Windows  через Perl

Tags: windows, perl

Посоветуйте, как можно реализовать  работу интерпретатора в среде Windows. Дело в том, что мне нужно, чтоб он выполнил те или иные функции с разными разделами. Что-то сделал в диске "С", потом, при выполнении определенных условии, то же самое, но в "D" или любом другом разделе либо вообще другом жестком. Как этого добиться? Если в Linux есть "корень" и все на него вешается, то в Windows такого нет...

Answer (score 1):

[Win32 API in Perl](http://www.osix.net/modules/article/?id=81)
,
[Win32::API](http://search.cpan.org/~acalpini/Win32-API-0.41/API.pm)

И дальше используешь информацию из MSDN, по необходимым тебе API

Comment: Не совсем понял что есть MSDN и прочая, но в какую сторону рыть - уяснил, на том спасибо.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx